# How to write a common API client for Tornado and non-Tornado services

Tags: python, httpclient, tornado

I have a web-service that exposes some API. I want to use this API in two applications, one is a command-line tool, and another is a web-server itself.

For the web-server, I am using Python tornado, so I am able to use `AyncHttpClient`, `gen.coroutine`, etc. But for the CLI, I can not use tornado since it needs an IOLoop to be running for async to work.

I am looking to create a kind of library that talks to the API, and re-use this library in CLI as well as web-service. This means that I should be able to write (possibly tornado gen) code on top of its functions to make it async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an IOLoop in your CLI tool?

```
@gen.coroutine
def main():
    client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield client.fetch('http://www.google.com')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

There's also the synchronous `tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient` which uses the same request and response objects as `AsyncHTTPClient`.

If you want to be HTTP-client-agnostic then you'll need to follow the example of oauthlib. Provide a base client that speaks in terms of HTTP headers and response bodies, and separately provide bindings from that client to various implementations like requests-oauthlib. (or just release the base client and expect your callers to figure out the mapping to their own HTTP implementation)

Comment: You mean using tornado in a CLI? I considered this but it seems to be overkill to import a whole web-framework library to use async-http, just so that I can use the same code in another service. This common API-library should be agnostic of any high level frameworks that might be used by its users. (The CLI and web-server may not be the only consumer of this library.)

Comment: Tornado isn't that heavyweight, but if you want to be HTTP-client-agnostic then you'll need to follow the example of [oauthlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauthlib). Provide a base client that speaks in terms of HTTP headers and response bodies, and separately provide bindings from that client to various implementations like [requests-oauthlib](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib). (or just release the base client and expect your callers to figure out the mapping to their own HTTP implementation)

Comment: I see your point. Just have a library that returns urls and other relevant headers, and the app itself can talk to them with their choice of http client. I like the idea. Can you mention that in this answer so that I can accept what I was looking for?

Comment: Edited to add oauthlib links to the main body.

Comment: I know this is a bit old ... but I am working on an [asynchronous CLI framework](https://github.com/ahopkins/asynccli) to do just this, and I was looking to see how other people have tackled this issue.